# Unable to run cqlsh shell commands from command line or python

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to run the SOURCE cqlsh shell command on a file from python and I'm having difficulty deciding on a solution. Originally I tried using the Cassandra Datastax driver to execute from the cursor but this resulted in the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2012, in execute
    return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state).result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3801, in result
    raise self._final_exception
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'SOURCE' ([SOURCE]...)">
```

I then attempted to run a shell command from my command line using the -e flag and got the following error:

```
sudo cqlsh -e "SOURCE '~/dev/cql_files/file.cql'" -k xxx 12.345.678.910 9160
Usage: cqlsh [options] [host [port]]

cqlsh: error: no such option: -e
```

The file executes if I use the -f flag to run:

```
sudo cqlsh -f cql_files/file.cql -k xxx 12.345.678.910 9160
```

Should I use subprocess library to call the above statement or should I open the file and execute each statement line by line? Which would be the better solution? Thanks!

Comment: which cassandra and cqlsh version are you using ?

Comment: Pro-tip: Don't specify the port.  Unless you're using a custom port, cqlsh will figure it out.  This will help as cqlsh uses 9042 as of 2.1, and 9160 in 2.0 and lower.